# tikz align baseline of labels in matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

Can I align the baseline of labels in a matrix of math nodes and at the same time have equally spaced equally sized boxes?

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of math nodes,
       nodes={
        draw,
        minimum height=6mm,
        minimum width =10mm,
        }]
 { a_{-2} & a_{-1} & a_0 \\  };
 \end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix [matrix of math nodes,
           nodes={
            draw,
            anchor=center,
            minimum height=6mm,
            minimum width =10mm,
            }]
  { a_{-2} & a_{-1} & a_0 \\  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

gives

[image: MWE]

On the left, the a_0 box is too high. On the right, the a_0 box is OK but the a_0 label is not aligned with the a_{-1} label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minus sign has a depth, because its bounding box is the same as for `+`. Smash it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix [matrix of math nodes,
           nodes={
            draw,
            anchor=center,
            minimum height=6mm,
            minimum width =10mm,
            }]
  { a_{\smash{-}2} & a_{\smash{-}1} & a_0 \\  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

(The arrow in the picture has been added to show the alignment.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add option `text depth=.25ex` to matrix definition.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix [matrix of math nodes,
           nodes={
            draw,
            anchor=center,
            minimum height=6mm,
            minimum width =10mm,
            text depth=.25ex,
            inner sep=0pt,
            }]
{ a_{-2} & a_{-1} & a_0 \\  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In the image below, the first one is the output of suggested edition.

[image]